# How to translate "Winter Bash"?

Tags: contemporary-latin, modern-life

The Stack Exchange Christmas celebration is here: [Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/).
If I were to discuss the event in Latin, what should I call it?
I mentioned it in [Conloquium (or chat room)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) and I simply called it *Saturnalia* due to the similarity in timing, but I assume there are better ideas out there.

There are many possible ways to approach this, so feel free to be creative.
I added one suggestion below, but I would like to hear more ideas and your thoughts on them.
If you have new ideas based on old answers, please post them as separate answers so people can vote for the best translations.

Comment: More translation ideas are still welcome! I will be happy to unaccept the currently accepted answer if there are better suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A key feature of the Winter Bash is having hats.
A particular kind of hat, [*pilleus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pileus_(hat)) also played a role in the Roman Saturnalia.
To emphasize the role of hats, I would suggest ***Saturnalia pilleata***.

Comment: "Saturnalia pilleata"--I find that very appealing in a "Royale with Cheese" kind of way *(this should be taken as the highest praise)*